# INITCAP in MariaDB constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, constraints

I am currently trying to create a constraint in MariaDB that checks that after every space there is an uppercase letter (just to check the correct format of people name) and I have tried with INITCAP but it doesn't let me do it in a check. Could you please help me to do it?

```
pepe Antonio -> It shouldn't go in
Pepe antonio -> It shouldn't go in
Pepe Antonio -> It should go in
```

Comment: Initial caps is biased against the Irish and Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `REGEXP` here with the following regex pattern:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE some_column REGEXP '^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$';
```

Follow the link below to see a running regex demo with your sample inputs:

### Demo

If you expect that the names might contain something other than uppercase and lowercase letters, we can adjust the pattern.

Comment: I think it could be easier, that's a difficult expression D:

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
name not regexp binary '(^| )[[:lower:]]'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f79812d355faaad8480163400b418af0) is a db<>fiddle.

The `binary` is because the more recent versions of MariaDB have case insensitive regular expression matching.  And you clearly care about case.

How does this work:

```
'(^| )[[:lower:]]'
--^ beginning of string
----^ space
-----^ expression has either one
------^ followed by a lower-case character
```

Of course, this is what you DON'T want.  Hence, the `NOT REGEXP`.

Comment: @user12866845 . . . Did you look at the db<>fiddle?

Comment: which is the purpose of the "binary" word?

Comment: @user12866845 . . . Yes, on db<>fiddle.  The `binary` keyword is needed because MariaDB (at least in the more recent versions) uses case-insenstive comparisons for regular expressions.